# Deny remote access to SQL Server which runs as a Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I run a SQL Server as a Docker container. Per default the container allows remote access.

Is there a way to prevent remote access?

Comment: Use a firewall? What do you mean by "remote" as in, connections not from within the container?

Comment: What do you currently have set up?  How could you access the container remotely?  (Do you just need to remove a `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` option?)

Comment: The sql server is accessible from another machine on the internet. Of course I do port mapping because I need access from the host machine via localhost.

Comment: *If* a machine on the internet can access it, that means you have port forwarding set on on your router, *and* the firewall is permitting connections on that port; a PC on the internet can't just access your PC unless the right networking requirements are put in place *and* the person on the other PC knows your external IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map the port, add 127.0.0.1 as the bound IP address. That will limit access to the mapped port to the host machine.

I.e. do something like

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```